# Different Languages for django username

Tags: python, regex, django, localization, chinese-locale

How to enable users to use other languages such as Chinese in username field using the usercreation form?

The methods I have tried:

1. modify the regex field of username field, failed
   What it tells me: the validation is not with the field, but the user model itself
2. encode the incoming input using encode("utf-8")
   What it tells me: the data i
3. client side utf transform...

This is the code in view:

```
def register_user(request):
    currentPath = request.POST.get('currentPath', '')
    currentPath = currentPath.replace("invalid/", "").replace("registered/", "")
    username=request.POST.get('email')
password=request.POST.get('password1')
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = MyRegistrationForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        user = auth.authenticate(username=username, password=password)

        if user is not None:
            auth.login(request, user)
        if "log" in currentPath:
            return HttpResponseRedirect(currentPath)
        else:
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/register_success')
    elif "log" in currentPath:
        return HttpResponseRedirect(currentPath + "registered")
else:
    form = MyRegistrationForm()
    form.fields['password1'].label = "密码"
    form.fields['password2'].label = "再次输入密码"
args = {}
args.update(csrf(request))

args['form'] = form

return render_to_response('register.html', args)
```

I think the form.save() is where the problem come from... that the validator automatically validates the field no matter what and chinese characters fail the validation.

And the following is the customized registration form, I have tried to override regex field with an username field but it doesn't work.

```
my_default_errors = {
    'required': '这个格子是必填的',
    'invalid': '请输入符合要求的值',
}
class MyRegistrationForm(UserCreationForm):
    error_messages = {
        'duplicate_username': ("同样的用户名已经被注册了"),
        'password_mismatch': ("和上次输入的不一样，请重新输入！"),
    }
# this variable defines a field in the customized form, not a model datafield
username = forms.RegexField(label = "用户名（其他所有人可见，请使用英文）", required=True, max_length=30,
    regex=r'^[\w.@+-\/\\]+$',
    error_messages=my_default_errors,)
email = forms.EmailField(label="邮箱（用于登录）" ,required=True, max_length = 75, error_messages = my_default_errors, )
password1 = forms.CharField(label= "密码", required=True, widget=forms.PasswordInput, error_messages = my_default_errors,)
password2 = forms.CharField(label= "请再次输入", required=True, widget=forms.PasswordInput, error_messages = my_default_errors,)

class Meta:
    model = User
    fields = ('username', 'email', 'password1', 'password2')

def clean_email(self):
    email = self.cleaned_data["email"]
    try:
        user = User.objects.get(email=email)
        raise forms.ValidationError("这个邮箱地址已被注册，是否忘记了密码？")
    except User.DoesNotExist:
        return email
def save(self, commit=True):
    user = super(UserCreationForm, self).save(commit=False)
    user.set_password(self.cleaned_data["password1"])
    user.email = self.cleaned_data["email"]
    user.is_active = True # change to false if using email activation
    if commit:
        user.save()   
    return user
```

Comment: Which version of Python and Django are you using? Also what do you use for user registration?

Comment: Python 2.3, Django 1.6, I just use user registration form to create new users... how do I accept Chinese in username field?

Comment: I suggest upgrading python to Python 2.6 as lower versions are not [compatible with Django 1.6](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/releases/1.6/#python-compatibility). Also, please share the form code and exact error trace you get.